# How to set the state selector for EditText underline?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I want to change EditText's underline color according to enabled, disabled and other states of the EditText. 
I found these attributes in styles.xml that changes the underline color, but I did not find anything releated to enabled, disabled states:

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/lightish_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/reddish</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/sunflower_yellow</item>
</style>
```

Comment: use this if you want to remove that underline android:background="@android:color/transparent"